# Bootstrap Carousel Example

Tags: bootstrap-carousel

I am trying to get my first Bootstrap example working. I am loading the Carousel example. I placed the css folder in the same folder as my .html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head co\
ntent must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesh\
eet">

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.j\
s"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media \
queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>                                                           
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></s\
cript>                                                                          
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></scrip\
t>                                                                              
<![endif]-->

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<!-- NAVBAR
```

I'd like to know how to make the actual **Carousel**

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: <link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">  ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <div id="carousel-id" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:First slide" alt="First slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzc3NyI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojN2E3YTdhO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+Rmlyc3Qgc2xpZGU8L3RleHQ+PC9zdmc+">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#6a6a6a/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzY2NiI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojNmE2YTZhO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+U2Vjb25kIHNsaWRlPC90ZXh0Pjwvc3ZnPg==">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item active">
        <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#5a5a5a/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzU1NSI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojNWE1YTVhO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+VGhpcmQgc2xpZGU8L3RleHQ+PC9zdmc+">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't just give away code like that. Make him understand what is wrong with his code, and how your code solves his problem, If you are trying to be helpful

Comment: Cool man! You can still explain him. And please edit your answer in such a way, that is helpful for further visitors!

Comment: This worked. I'm not sure I understand how I was supposed to know this? When I look at the documentation it all calls bootstrap locally http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: They are just giving you an example of what the typical Bootstrap setup would look like. All you have to do is replace the css link, js link to their CDN links and voila, you're in business. Be sure to check out the pro/cons of using the CDN service over hosting the files on your own server. Glad this helped @dstung.

Comment: @gates - **dstung**'s question was how to do it, not why it's not working. Do you see any code in the question? No.

Answer (score 1):

I will share a code that i think is much more simple to understand and will help you with your Carousel example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>
      Carousel Example
    </title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
     //i am not using any CSS (styling) but you can use some if you want.
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">

            </li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">

            </li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">

            </li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
           //remember to give a valid image here
                <img src="Images/joker.jpg" alt="lincoln">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>First Slide</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="Images/joker.jpg" alt="lincoln">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>Second Slide</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="Images/joker.jpg" alt="lincoln">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>Third Slide</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       //now we will use glyphicons to slide left and right between our pictures
        <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previouse</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd say you should make a code snippet not just type code. You see the above answer has a snippet.